# How can i extend my partition further than the limit? Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

So I am trying to make my partition full size but there seems to be a limit. I am on OS X 10.8.5 using Disk Utility.

[image]

I am using a MacBook 4,1 (early 2008)

Ok so I used MacPostFactor to install mountain lion with my friends copy of the installer. I deleted my Lion partition.

The output of `diskutil cs list` and `sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
Last login: Mon Nov 21 17:00:35 on ttys001
Daniels-MacBook:~ danieljensen$ diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
Daniels-MacBook:~ danieljensen$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  117650752         
  118060392  106863504      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  224923896    9517712      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  234441608          7         
  234441615         32         Sec GPT table
  234441647          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: You can't move the beginning of an existing partition to "lower" physical block numbers (with 0 is the first block and 234441647 the last block and your *Mountain Lion* partition starts somewhere in the middle) with Disk Utility. Either use a third-party tool like iPartition or create a new partition in the empty space and clone/restore  *Mountain Lion* to it. Then delete   *Mountain Lion (old)* and expand   *Mountain Lion(new)* to the full size. Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0` entered in Terminal to your question.

Comment: without knowing more it's VERY hard to approach this.
could you type
`diskutil cs list` and post the answer. this should print out the specific hard drive volume information needed to answer this question properly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac officially doesn't support Mountain Lion so the how-to below may fail!

---

You can't move ("backward-expand") the beginning of an existing partition to "lower" physical block numbers (with 0: the first block and 234441647: the last block and your Mountain Lion partition starts somewhere in the middle) with Disk Utility.

You will be able to create a new partition in the unallocated disk space and restore your existing *Mountain Lion* partition to it though. Then remove the old partition and expand the new one to the full size.

Since your Mac can't boot to Internet Recovery Mode, you need a second boot media (e.g. a thumb drive) with a basic system or a full fledged system.

- Create a bootable Lion thumb drive
- Boot to the thumb drive
- Open Terminal and enter `diskutil list` and (assuming your internal disk has the disk identifier disk0) `sudo gpt -r show disk0` to get an overview
- Unmount your internal disk:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  ```
- Add a partition in the unallocated disk space:

  ```
  sudo gpt add -i 4 -b 409640 -s 117650752 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- Enter `diskutil list` and get the identifier of the new partition with the size 60.2 GB (your original ML volume has the size 57.1 GB). This may be disk0s2 or disk0s4
- Format the partition with newfs_hfs:

  ```
  newfs_hfs -v "New" -J /dev/disk0sX #use the proper identifier here
  ```
- Close Terminal and open Disk Utility
- Restore the *Mountain Lion* volume to *New*.
- Boot to the restored *Mountain Lion* volume (AFAIR you will see two volumes with the name *Mountain Lion* in *StartVolume*, so boot to the proper one!) to check if it works.
- If everything works open Disks Utility and remove the second *Mountain Lion* partition. Expand the first *Mountain Lion* to the full size.